# Attempting to make a special counter

Tags: python

In Python I'm attempting to make a **product_ID** generator, which takes a number of any value and converts it into a hexadecimal format of "#AA0000". When the 4 numbers overflow past 9999, they increment the first letter by one in the ASCII uppercase set. Meaning if I give 10000 as input, I get #AB0001.

Currently I am using the modulus operator (%) to find the remainder of the input number so it is always within 4 digits. (For reference, the formula I used was Numb%9999.)

The issue I am currently having with is getting the second letter to increment properly. I've managed to get a single letter version working, which you can see here:

```py
from string import ascii_uppercase as upper
upper = [a for a in upper]

def Convert_Numb_To_Ref(Order_Number):
    """Takes an Order_Number (int), and converts it into a unique Order_ID"""
    Number = str((Order_Number%9999)+1) # Makes it so it never is bigger than 4 digits
    Number = ("0"*(4-len(str(Number))))+Number # If number < 1000, adds on 0s to the beginning, so 1 -> 0001
    try:
        Letter = upper[Order_Number//9999] # Divides and floors
    except IndexError:
        print("Number too large! Cannot generate Product_ID")
        return False
    return f"#{Letter}{Number}"
```

If I was to input 10000, I would get #B0002.

This works fine, returning what I want to see. (Currently the above code only works with a single letter, which is why there aren't 2.) I'm just stuck with incrementing the second letter.

Comment: Are you aware of the ``hex`` function? Also, note that ``Order_Number%9999`` restricts the number to 4 digits *excluding 9999*. Compare ``9 % 9`` to ``9 % 10``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```py
Letter = upper[Order_Number//9999] # Divides and floors
```

If the order number becomes too large, the index becomes larger than 25, so you would get an `IndexError`. To avoid this, you should use "modulo 26" to get a number lower than 26. And you should do another lookup for the next letter (the left one).

Some other remarks:

- To separate the high part and the low part you should not divide by 9999 but by 10000 (idem for the module operation), unless you want to skip the number 9999 (or 0000). This is not entirely clear from your question.
- For the digits you can use standard Python formatting: `'%04d' % nr` will do the trick.

Putting it together you could write something like this:

```py
import string


def number_to_reference(order_number):
    """Take an order number and convert it into a unique order id."""
    if order_number >= 26 * 26 * 10000:
        print("Number too large! Cannot generate Product_ID")
        return False
        # NB: You could also do the following instead:
        # raise ValueError('Number too large! Cannot generate Product_ID')

    high_part = order_number // 10000
    low_part = order_number % 10000

    letter1 = string.ascii_uppercase[high_part // 26]
    letter2 = string.ascii_uppercase[high_part % 26]
    return '#%s%s%04d' % (letter1, letter2, low_part)


print(number_to_reference(1))        # AA0001
print(number_to_reference(123))      # AA0123
print(number_to_reference(9999))     # AA9999
print(number_to_reference(10000))    # AB0000
print(number_to_reference(1234567))  # ET4567
print(number_to_reference(6759999))  # ZZ9999
print(number_to_reference(6760000))  # Number too large! Cannot generate Product_ID
```